# GetSharedDefaultFolder - Subfolder Access Error

Tags: vba, outlook

I am having trouble getting my Outlook VBA code to recognize the subfolder in my Shared Tasks.
What I'm trying to do is create a macro that will automatically create a task in the department Shared Task folder. Tried Googling a variety of solutions to no avail. The code goes as follows:

```
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

Dim defaultTasksFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim subFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace

Dim objMail As MailItem

Dim objItm As TaskItem

Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set objNS = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set objMail = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
Set objOwner = objNS.CreateRecipient("name@email.com")
objOwner.Resolve
If objOwner.Resolved Then
Set defaultTasksFolder = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderTasks)
subFolder = defaultTasksFolder.Folders("TestFolder") **ERROR OCCURS HERE - OBJECT COULD NOT BE FOUND**
Set objItm = subFolder.Items.Add(olTaskItem)

With objItm
.Subject = "Name- " & objMail.Subject
.StartDate = objMail.ReceivedTime
.Body = objMail.Body

End With

objItm.Save

MsgBox ("Task Created for e-mail: " & vbCrLf & objMail.Subject)
End If


End Sub
```

It errors out on *subFolder = defaultTasksFolder.Folders("TestFolder")*, saying that the object could not be found. I double and tripled checked the folder name.

Any ideas what might be causing this error? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add the `Logon` method before accessing MAPI, it will log to the profile if Outlook has just been started. If it is already running it will not affect anything. Then try to add both mailboxes as delegate stores (see the `Advanced` tab of the `Exchange account properties` dialog). You should see both mailboxes.

Finally, I'd try to iterate over all folders before to make sure the folder exists.  Also, I'd recommend checking the recipient's name.

Comment: Hey Eugene, thanks for your response. Actually used some of your other posts for this code..With regards to `Advanced` tab of the `Exchange account properties` dialog, nope, nothing there. We are a large organisation and I doubt that I would be allowed to have additional mailboxes of other employees added to my account (if I'm understanding your comment correctly). Given that I am able to create tasks in the shared list manually, I presume permissions or access are not the issue. For iteration of other folders, do you mean looping through all folders to find the correct one? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, do you see the required folder when you iterate over all subfolders?

Comment: It seems that no, Outlook cannot actually find that Folder when looping through existing folders - I used this code: [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/4508-outlook-search-by-folder-name.html). Plus, when I look in the properties of the shared folder, the "Location:" field is blank, whereas my task folders have "\\me@email.com" direction listed. But as I mentioned in the comment above, I can see the folder and create tasks manually, i.e. going into the Tasks tab, selecting the folder and creating a task. So, this is strange. I'll keep digging in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Outlook might cache only the default folders, but not their suborders.
Can you see and access the subfolder in Outlook?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, yeah, I can see the folder and create tasks manually, i.e. going into the Tasks tab, selecting the folder and creating a task. I can also see tasks created by others in the same folder. I have permission level of "Owner" too, if that matters, although I already have a code to resolve ownership, which works when I execute the code. It only errors out on the subfolder part. I know the code is fine because it works when using a default task folder for my own account. The issue only comes in when Shared Folder is used, somehow.